# Why is the first solution way much slower than the second one, to calculate the sum of prime numbers?

Tags: python, performance, primes

I was solving a Euler's project problem (in python) where I had to calculate the sum of all prime numbers below 2 million, I came up with two solution but only one got me the result because the other one was too slow. This is my first solution that was too slow:

```
n=2000000
list = list(range(2,n,1))

for x in list :
    if(x*x>n):
        break

    for d in range(x,n,x):
        if((x!=d) and (d in list) ):
            list.remove(d)
            continue


result=sum(list)        
print(result)
```

This is my second solution, which was pretty fast at calculating the sum:

```
n=2000000
list = list(range(2,n,1))
temp=list
for x in list :
    if(x*x>n):
        break
    if(temp[x-2]==0):
        continue
    for d in range(x,n,x):
        if(x!=d):
            temp[d-2]=0

result=sum(list)        
print(result)
```

What I would like to know is why the last one calculated the sum almost instantaneously while the other didn't even produce a result after several minutes?

Comment: You've optimized your algorithm. Congrats.

Comment: The `(d in list)` is not helping the runtime of your first snippet

Comment: Also you'd potentially hit an `IndexError` since you call `list.remove()` while iterating over it.

Comment: You shouldn't use the variable name `list`, as it overwrites the built-in `list`. Also, doing `test=list` is pointless, as both variables point to the same list in memory and editing one will edit the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the number of loops in your code. In the first solution, you have around 4 loops `for x in list`,  `for d in range(x,n,x):`, `(d in list)` and `list.remove(d)` also loop through the list to remove d. But in case of the second solution, you have only two loop `for x in list :` and  `for d in range(x,n,x):`

Comment: Yes, it does.  `(d in list)` is an O(n) operation for lists, which is already in a doubly nested for loop.  You do not have this same operation in your second snippet.

Comment: Let's understand this using an example. Let's say n = 10 than in your first case total number of statement executed is 10*10*10*10 = 10000 and in second case it's 10*10 = 100

Comment: You can refer https://youtu.be/eKp56OLhoQs it's like finding all primes quickly and then you can add them. You can also learn more about this kind of algorithm here https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/prime-numbers/

Comment: @RodrigoPina if you want to improve the performance, you can remove numbers you know for sure aren't primes from your original list - namely all even numbers other than the number 2.